Display button for each index
I have to show barcode button for unpaid payments.Am looping the unpaid payments but still two barcodes are displayed for one payment.Here is the code snippet.I have two table payments and payment records both of them are connected through foreign key payment_id.Each payment has payment records.The payment records table consist of field called barcode url.Now I want to display the corresponding barcode_url for each payment
What should I do ? Current it displays all the barcode buttons to a payment
Somebody please help !.
Controller method is described below
def payments
 @paid_payments = current_user.get_valid_paid_payments.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    @unpaid_payments = current_user.get_valid_unpaid_payments.order(created_at: :desc)
    payment_records = PaymentRecord.where(payment_id: @unpaid_payments.pluck(:id))
    @barcode_data = payment_records.each_with_object({}) do |record, hash|
      hash[record.payment_id] = record.barcode_url
    end`your text`
    @smartpit = current_user.smartpits.take
    @user = current_user
    render :layout => 'mypage'
end

View file
<div class="container">
   <div class="vertical-center center-barcode">
    <% @unpaid_payments.each do |payment| %>
        <% barcode_url = @barcode_data[payment.id] %>
           <% if barcode_url.present? %>
             <a href="<%= barcode_url %>" class="btn btn-danger" target="_blank">
                 <%= t 'users.bill_detail.new_payment_method_barcode' %>
             </a>
           <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>


The core problem here is really bad modeling. You're most likely missing an assocation that would let you just call payment.bar_code_url so that you don't have to do the steps of looping through the records and creating a hash. Rethink instead of just piling on more junk code. If you need help with that provide an example of your models.

@max,I don't have the permission to edit the table
payments` table:
id,simcard_id,simacrd_type,payment_moth,paymnet_from,amount,tax_rate,status,due_date,payment_type,serial_number,currency,created_at,updated_at,paid_At,payment_method,secret_code,clicked_from_email_or_sms,clicked_at
Payment_records
id,payment_id,amount_tax,status,message_smatpit_no,skeyuo_id,nihao_id,barcode_url
